# AJAX and processing a PHP page - not playing together

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is a followup to a previous post of mine where the main questions I had centered around FullCalendar. Now, I have narrowed the suspects down to a problem between my main page and the PHP page that fetches data.

The "events.php" page returns data just fine when I run it by itself, so there's no problem internal to the page. All the problems with the JSON have been worked out, so the data being returned is OK (I just pasted it into the "events" line. Also, when in Chrome, and I click on the error then the "response" tab in the error panel (F12), it says "The Request has no response data available". Just manually copy the query string into a URL and paste it into Chrome address bar, the PHP file returns data just fine.

So, here are three parts: my main page, the PHP, and a screenshot of Chrome. ANY insight as to how I can fix this? Pleeeeease... :)

-- HERE'S the resolution. Unlike the code that I got from ([here](http://developer-paradize.blogspot.com/2013/06/jquery-fullcalendar-integration-with.html)), **I shouldn't have used** "localhost:8888/fullcalendar/events.php". I even tried "http://mydomain.com/tpsdb/fullcalendar/events.php", and it didn't work. SO.... I just used "events.php", and **it works!! Thanks guys for helping!** I am not too familiar with cross-domain security, but the original paths were correctly typed (I checked a dozen times)...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();


            var calendar =
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                editable: true,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },

                eventSources: [
                    {
                        url: 'http://localhost:8888/tpsdb/fulcalendar/events.php',
                        type: 'GET',
                        data: {},
                        error: function () {
                            alert('There was an error while fetching events!');
                        }
                    }
                ],

                // Convert the allDay from string to boolean
                eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
                    if (event.allDay === 'true') {
                        event.allDay = true;
                    } else {
                        event.allDay = false;
                    }
                },
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                    var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                    var url = prompt('Type Event url, if exits:');
                    if (title) {
                        var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                        var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'http://localhost:8888/fullcalendar/add_events.php',
                            data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&url='+ url ,
                            type: "POST",
                            success: function(json) {
                                alert('Added Successfully');
                            }
                        });
                        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                                {
                                    title: title,
                                    start: start,
                                    end: end,
                                    allDay: allDay
                                },
                                true // make the event "stick"
                        );
                    }
                    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                },

                editable: true,
                eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
                    var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://localhost:8888/fullcalendar/update_events.php',
                        data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function(json) {
                            alert("Updated Successfully");
                        }
                    });
                },
                eventResize: function(event) {
                    var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://localhost:8888/fullcalendar/update_events.php',
                        data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function(json) {
                            alert("Updated Successfully");
                        }
                    });

                }

            });

        });

    </script>
    <style>
        body {
            margin-top: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;

        }
        #calendar {
            width: 900px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, the PHP page called "events.php"

```
<?php
    // List of events
    $json = array();

    // Query that retrieves events
    $requete = "SELECT * FROM evenement ORDER BY id";

    // connection to the database
    include ('../includes/functions.php');

    // Execute the query
    $resultat = $bdd->query($requete) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));

    // sending the encoded result to success page
    $tempjson =  json_encode($resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    $tempjson = str_replace('"false"', 'false', $tempjson);
    echo $tempjson;

?>
```

And finally the screenshot...
[image: Chrome Screenshot]

Comment: The urls in the code don't seem to match the ones in the screenshot. Are you sure you didn't forgot `/tpsdb` in the path of the failed request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using /fullcalendar/update_events.php only instead of adding the host:port. Looks like you are using different hosts for page and ajax. This will ensure that your code works when publishing on a server.

Also, as Bergi said, fullcalendar/update_events.php is in root or inside  tpsdb folder?

if you are using another host, then you might be end up with Cross domain security, you need to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin policy in header on the php file

Comment: Thanks you! I think that was part of it!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `dataType: "json"` to your event source, and/or have your PHP script clearly state that it returns json :

```
//PHP
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//Javascript
eventSources: [
                {
                    url: 'http://localhost:8888/tpsdb/fulcalendar/events.php',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {},
                    dataType: 'json',   //<-- add this line
                    error: function () {
                        alert('There was an error while fetching events!');
                    }
                }
            ],
```